# GitLab CI/CD : detect when a merge request is reverted

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there any way to run a pipeline when a merge request is reverted on GitLab CI/CD? I tried to debug environment variables with those two jobs but they are not triggered :

```yaml
stages:
  - test

debug:
  stage: test
  script:
    - printenv
  when: always

debug2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - printenv
  rules:
    # Run only during merge requests
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: always
      allow_failure: false
```

I would like to roll back a deployment made with PHP Deployer over SSH when a merge request on a deployment branch is reverted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with was checking for the title of the merge-request if the revert is done via a merge-request. As Gitlab names reverts of commits with the pattern "Revert + `$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`", you can check if the `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE` contains the word "Revert":

```
revert:deploy:
  stage: revert
  script:
    - echo "reverting deployment..."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^Revert/ && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```